# Does check style 80 character rule still making sense today?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have recently started doing some Java and one of the Maven checkstyle plugin is pissing me off, specially the 80 chars per line rule !

```
"Line is longer than 80 characters!"
```

I have managed to fix most of the checkstyle "compile error" generated by the Maven plugin automatically via a Eclipse checkstyle plugin but many of the the 80 chars error still needs manual fix despite I have fiddled with the formatter for quite a while....

What makes it worse is it makes the code looks ugly, breaking function deceleration,class deceleration, assignment into 2/3 line,

Some of the checkstyle is good which helps us get the code clean but some rules just looks stupid and total waste of time !

This makes me wondering does the 80 chars checkstyle still making any sense in the modern computer age ? I just failed to understand why java team still use it, it has been causing more trouble than helping us get the code clean & in a good style...

Comment: I agree and therefor we have simply changed that checkstyle rule instead of ranting out loud.

Comment: I will discuss with the java team but I want to have a general idea first !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No.

I certainly makes sense to limit the length of lines, since long lines are hard to read. And monitor space is still limited. I often work on a laptop or two smallish 19" displays. With multiple editors open, long lines start to disapear on the right.

The specific limit of 80 characters (or the more strict version of 72) today is kind of arbitrary. And a team should decide on what works for them.

Probably 120 characters makes more sense, so it fits into tweet with some space for hashtags ;-)

Comment: Even 120 would make more sense than the pathetic 80... For some long declaration line I have to break them into 3 lines ...